# How can I hide a secret password from being printed to the command line?

Tags: security, gradle, command-line, terminal

When I run a gradle command, it outputs `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` values to the command line:

```
./gradlew :app:assemble
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dhttps.proxyUser=ME -Dhttps.proxyPassword=PASSWORD123
```

If I am screen sharing with a co-worker, this is a security risk, especially if the session is recorded. How can I solve for this?

note: these values are picked up from global `gradle.properties`

Comment: Doesn't the simple answer solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Write the password into a file, let it name `proxyPassword.txt`.

Then use

```sh
./gradlew :app:assemble
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: 
-Dhttps.proxyUser=ME 
-Dhttps.proxyPassword=`cat proxyPassword.txt`
```

Watch the `` ` `` [command substitution](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution)

If you fear that your file is not proper, may contain some more lines, you can use `head -1 proxyPassword.txt` instead of `cat`