# if i know key=iv=text, can i crack AES?

Tags: bash, encryption, aes

The thing is, i want to encrypt some information on my disk.

The method i choose to encrypt my text is:

```
read pwd
key=${pwd}
iv=${pwd}
encrypt_info = $(echo ${text} | openssl enc -e -A -aes-256-cbc -a -K ${key} -iv ${iv} -nosalt)
```

But I do not want to enter my password every time I encrypt my information. So i put my "pubkey" somewhere public. The "pubkey" is generated in this way:

```
read password
pubkey=$(echo ${password} | openssl enc -e -A -aes-256-cbc -a -K ${password} -iv ${password} -nosalt)
```

I only enter my password every time i want to decrypt my text. Steps to decrypt:

1. Enter password
2. Calculate "pubkey" in the way above
3. If the pubkeys match, the password is the correct one.
4. Use the correct password to decrypt my information.

You see my steps. My question is, if some one get my "pubkey" and know that the "pubkey" is generated by the way above, can he/she crash my password?

Comment: In effect you are creating your own password hashing algorithm for verifying the password. Your algorithm suffers from at least all the defects of any unsalted password hashing algorithm, namely lack of iteration and most importantly vulnerability to precomputation/rainbow table attacks. Amusingly, if you look at the CBC mode the 1st block of cipher is E_K(IV xor plaintext), but in your case both your IV and your plaintext are the same (K), so you have E_K(0).

Answer (score 1):

> openssl enc -e -A -aes-256-cbc -a -K ${password} -iv ${password} -nosalt)

With aes-256 the *key* needs to have 32 bytes and *iv* needs to have 16 bytes, so  properly you cannot use the same value (it works for aes-128 though).

You are using the *password* as a key (`-K` parameter), so let's use a proper denotation *key*, which in this case should be 32 bytes hex encoded.

> if some one get my "pubkey" and know that the "pubkey" is generated by the way above, can he/she crash my password?

no, that shouldn't be possible

> 3. If the pubkeys match, the password is the correct one.
> 4. Use the correct password to decrypt my information.

I don't really understand the reason behind the step. You can just try to decrypt the file and if the key is not current, the decryption fails on invalid padding.

Or - do you want to validate the key once when provided by the user? In that case you could validate a *hash* of the password

`echo 'some password' | openssl dgst -sha256`

Usually storing a simple hash of a user password is not secure enough, but assuming you provide a random 256 bit key, it should be ok.

> iv=${pwd}

This seems to be a vulnerability, the `cbc` mode needs a random IV to be secure. Reusing the IV for multiple encryptions is not secure.

Maybe just let the *openssl* generate a random salt (and derive the key and IV from the salt and password) would solve the problem.

`echo -n 'some text' | openssl enc -e -A -aes-128-cbc -k 'password' -a`

Comment: I'm new to encryption and openssl, but your answer is clear and helpful. Thank you so much.

Comment: [small addition to hide the password](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67712778/1820553) from printed on the command line. 10K congratulations.